# Statistical method to test if a set of values is similar to a group of known similar sets of values

Tags: hypothesis-testing, dataset, prediction, goodness-of-fit

I am not sure if this is to be asked here - 
I am working and interpreting data related to certain events. I noticed that a particular subset of values always seem to match events which is of particular interest.

The issue is that I have had to manually check each event if its correct or not.
So I have a curated group of 10 such "datasets". Now I am not statistically inclined but I was wondering if one of the goodness of fit test or something similar - to see an 11th dataset is similar to previous 10.

for e.g. -

I have a machine of certain configuration of gears. The gears can be of any of three materials - Iron, Bronze or Copper. I measure the thickness of each gear in millimeters (mm). I now notice 10 different configurations of various gears allow the machine to run for 24 hours before breaking down. The tables below denote the material of each gear and thickness of said gear. There are 9 gears in each configuration.

```
dataset 1

Iron    Bronze    Copper
12      8         2
14      7         4
11.5    8      
        9

dataset 2

Iron    Bronze    Copper
11      8         2
13      7         4
15                3          
12.5  

dataset 3

Iron    Bronze    Copper
11      8         2
13      7         4
        9.5
        8
        8.5                          

.....
and so on till dataset 10
.....


     dataset 10

Iron    Bronze    Copper
11      8         2
13                4
15                3          
                  3
                  3.5
```

Now say I have an 11th such dataset

```
         dataset 11

Iron    Bronze    Copper
11      8         2
13      10.5      4
15                3          
12
```

Is there any statistical test, that can say if this particular dataset is similar to the previous 10 and a likely candidate for a machine configuration that will successfully run for 24 hours ?

I hope I was able to articulate my question properly - any help in this regard will be appreciated.

Comment: For each machine, do you have data on how long it ran? Do you have any censoring?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by 'censoring'. but for the first part - I am not sure - I think the data can be acquired, but I am interested in if a configuration will allow for a machine to run for atleast 24 hours.

Comment: A Naive way would be to calculate distances. You have a total of 9x3 attributes(3 attributes of Iron,Bronze,Copper) per gear. This also requires you to have your gears 'numbered'.